# Scintilla- Can't compile bait example

Tags: c, scintilla

I'm tring to compile the [bait example](http://www.scintilla.org/bait.zip) from the Scintilla website. I have had ZERO luck in getting it to compile. I can compile scintilla itself just fine, as well as scite but bait is a different story. When I try and compile with the supplied Makefile, I get the following error:

```
bait.c:1:21: fatal error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory
```

I have GTK, and using different versions of it.I've tried It doesn't seem to matter what I do. I've scowered the Internet for help, read through man page after man page and I just can't figure out what the problem is. If I don't get that error, then I just get another one.

Here's  the original makefile:

```
.SUFFIXES: .c .o .h .a

INCLUDEDIRS=-I../scintilla/include
CXXFLAGS= -DGTK -DSCI_LEXER -W -Wall
LEXEROBJS=$(wildcard ../scintilla/gtk/Lex*.o)

all: bait

shiz:
gcc `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-2.0` $(INCLUDEDIRS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
bait: bait.o $(LEXEROBJS) ../scintilla/bin/scintilla.a
gcc `pkg-config --libs gtk+-2.0 gthread-2.0` -lstdc++ -DGTK $^ -o $@
clean:
rm -rf bait *.o
```

I've also tried using GtkScintilla from codebrainz. I can't even make that work. I always get either the above error, or an error saying:

```
fatal error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory
```

I'd really appreciate any and all help on this. Thank you.

Edit: I'm using Linux Mint

Comment: where is gtk.h located in your system? (ie. result of `find . -name "gtk.h"`)

Comment: That returns nothing at all... which is very odd.

Comment: Which means you lack the proper header file. Are you certain you installed the library correctly?

Comment: I know that I have GTK. I can compile GTK programs. I don't know what changes here.

Also, I don't know if the find command is even working properly, as I can't get it to return anything.

Comment: That error is gone now... and I have got it to make an object file, but there are a lot of undefined reference problems now... lots and lots. I'd post them, if that'd be helpful.

Comment: find returns nothing if there is nothing to find. (try it out on a file you know exists and see the difference). It's possible you need to try it from root with different permissions `su` then once you're root `cd /` then rerun the find command. Do you know what version of gtk you're using? (2, 3, something older?) You said you were able to compile before? What was the command you used?

Comment: gcc -Wall helloworld.c -o helloworld $(pkg-config --cflags --libs    gtk+-3.0)

That works for a simple hello world program. I'm very confused now. :/ Thank you for helping though. I do appreciate that. :)

Comment: hmm... one more idea, try these two commands: `cd /usr/include` then `ls | grep "gtk"` same thing in `/usr/lib`. Do you see any "gtk" type directories in there? I'm thinking the paths in the makefile are wrong

Comment: Result from looking in usr/include: 


gtk-2.0
gtk-3.0
gtk-unix-print-2.0
polkit-gtk-mate-1


Result from looking in /usr/lib:


gtk-2.0
gtk-3.0
gtk-sharp-beans
+ bunches of libs.

Answer (score 1):

Coming back to this... If you've already solved the issue please let me know. What it's starting to look like is this is more trouble than it's worth. :)

here's what I did:

1. Install Mint 13 on my virtual box
2. libgtk-3-dev (and supporting packages)
3. verify I could build with `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0`
4. found gtk.h (`/usr/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtk.h`) and supporting files
5. downloaded bait example

Here's the problems:

1. bait's Makefile has references to gtk+-2.0 which you need to change to 3.0
2. bait's Makefile requires you to build in a specific directory (note the `INCLUDEDIRS` needs you to be in the scintilla directory
3. archive scintilla.a needs to be built (it's not provided and is required for bait.o)
4. building the archive needs you to modify the makefile (comment out these lines:

   `ifdef GTK3`
   `else`
   `GTKVERSION=gtk+-2.0`
   `endif`
5. Once you fix that and build the archive there's about a million more undefined references in: `ScintillaGTK.cxx:(.text+0x1374)` and the like..

Anyway. I'll give it a little more time, let me know if you close this issue yourself!

Comment: I thought that might work, but I have already tried that and I have exactly the same result, I'm afraid. I appreciate the attempt, in any case. This is a confusing one. :/

Answer (score -1):

i've done with this makefile

```
##### Makefile #####
# Make file for bait on Linux or compatible OS
# Released to the public domain 2000 by Neil Hodgson neilh@scintilla.org
# This makefile tested with GCC 3.2 and GNOME 2.0

.SUFFIXES: .c .o .h .a

ifdef GTK3
GTKVERSION=gtk+-3.0
else
GTKVERSION=gtk+-2.0
endif

INCLUDEDIRS=-I../scintilla/include
CXXFLAGS= -DGTK -DSCI_LEXER -W -Wall
LEXEROBJS=$(wildcard ../scintilla/gtk/Lex*.o)

all: bait

.c.o:
    gcc `pkg-config --cflags $(GTKVERSION)` $(INCLUDEDIRS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
bait: bait.o $(LEXEROBJS) ../scintilla/bin/scintilla.a
    gcc -DGTK $^ -o $@ -lstdc++ `pkg-config --libs $(GTKVERSION) gthread-2.0` -lm -lgmodule-2.0
clean:
    rm -rf bait *.o
```